# Implementing Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm working with fractional derivatives, primarily Riemann-Liouville and Caputo derivatives. In these definitions `n=Ceiling[\alpha]`, and `a` is chosen to be 0. They are defined as:

[image: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2014/238459/]

[image: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2014/238459/]

I implemented the Caputo fractional derivative on `Sech[x]` like so

```
derivC[q_, x_] := Module[{s=Ceiling[q]}, If[FractionalPart[q]==0, D[Sech[x], {x, s}], 1/Gamma[s-q] NIntegrate[Derivative[s][Sech][x-u] u^(s-q-1), {u,0,x}]]]
```

Inside the integrand we change variables `x->t` in accordance with the definition then `x-t->u` for ease of computation. Inside the integrand we take an integer number of derivatives on `Sech` and then integrate with a power law. If the order of the derivative `q` is integer then it should reduce to an integer-order derivative. Then using `NIntegrate` I integrate up to a bound `x` that's a real number because it is given by the function wrapper.

Whew! Long backstory.

The problem with implementing the Riemann-Liouville derivative though is that you take the integer number of derivatives outside of the integral. Since I'm using `NIntegrate` I only have numbers, not a function, which would make the derivative 0.

I do not know of a way to implement this. Any help or hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6139

Comment: [`FractionalD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalD.html) and [`CaputoD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CaputoD.html) are introduced in _v13.1_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To obtain derivatives of a numerical integral, one can try inactivating the integral, then differentiate, then activate. For example:

```
Inactive[NIntegrate][(x-ξ)^n f[ξ], {ξ, 0, x}];
D[%, x]
```

> 0^n f[x] + 
>    Inactive[NIntegrate][n (x - ξ)^(-1 + n) f[ξ], {ξ, 0, x}]

The problem with this approach is that in your application, $n<0$, and so differentiating this form of the integral is not useful. However, I again suggest that you transform the integration variable $\xi \to x - u$. Then:

```
Inactive[NIntegrate][u^n f[x-u], {u, 0, x}];
D[%, x]
```

> x^n f[0] + Inactive[NIntegrate][u^n Derivative[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PesJp.png)[f][-u + x], {u, 0, x}]

This version doesn't suffer from fatal divide by 0 issues. We can package up the above ideas into a function:

```
RLDerivative[α_][f_] := With[{s = 1/Gamma[Ceiling[α]-α]},
    RLFunction[
        α,
        f,
        Function[{x,ϵ},
            Evaluate @ D[
                s Inactive[NIntegrate][u^(Ceiling[α]-α-1)f[x-u], {u, 0, ϵ I, x}],
                {x, Ceiling[α]}
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

RLFunction[α_, f_, func_][x_?NumericQ] := Replace[
    Quiet @ Check[Activate[func[x,0]], $Failed],
  $Failed :> (Message[RLFunction::ipath]; Activate[func[x, .1]])
]

RLFunction::ipath = "Unable to achieve convergence along the real axis. Integral path was deformed";
```

First note that I changed the path of integration to include $i \epsilon$. The default is to use $\epsilon =0$. However, there can be situations where the numerical integral doesn't converge. In that case, deforming the path of the integral can avoid this convergence issue. One down side is that using a complex path can introduce a spurious machine epsilon imaginary part. The other issue is the function under consideration may have a pole near $i \epsilon$ which will cause the deformed path integration to return an incorrect result.

Next, I split up the computation into two pieces. `RLDerivative[α][f]` will return an `RLFunction` object that can be applied to `x` values. This way the derivative of the inactive [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) object only needs to be done once.

With those caveats mentioned, let's see how it works. First a test case that can be performed exactly:

```
int[n_, x_] = Integrate[(x-ξ)^n Exp[ξ], {ξ, 0, x}];
rlexp[α_, x_] := 1/Gamma[Ceiling[α]-α] D[int[Ceiling[α]-α-1, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], Ceiling[α]}]/. \[FormalX]->x
```

Now, compare `RLDerivative` with the exact `rlexp`:

```
rf = RLDerivative[.9][Exp];
rf /@ Range[5]
rlexp[.9, Range[5]//N]

rf = RLDerivative[12.2][Exp];
rf /@ Range[5]
rlexp[12.2, Range[5]//N]
```

> {2.75781, 7.40346, 20.0932, 54.603, 148.416}
>
> {2.75781, 7.40346, 20.0932, 54.603, 148.416}
>
> {1.12015*10^7, 2211.05, 34.6723, 55.0066, 148.438}
>
> {1.12015*10^7, 2211.05, 34.6723, 55.0066, 148.438}

Now, for an example where the default integral path has convergence issues:

```
rf = RLDerivative[.9][Sin];
rf[.9]
```

> RLFunction::ipath: Unable to achieve convergence along the real axis. Integral path was deformed
>
> 0.698049 + 2.99218*10^-14 I

Notice the warning message and the appearance of the small imaginary part resulting from the deformed path. Finally, the `RLFunction` looks like:

```
RLDerivative[1.9][Sin]

(*
RLFunction[1.9, Sin, 
 Function[{x$, ϵ$}, 
  0.105114 (1/x$^0.9 + 
     Inactive[NIntegrate][Sin[u - x$]/u^0.9, {u, 0, I ϵ$, x$}])]]
*)
```

This looks a bit ugly, so here is a [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules for `RLFunction`, intended to mimic the standard M11 appearance of summary boxes for these types of functions:

```
RLFunction /: MakeBoxes[RLFunction[a_, f_, _], StandardForm] := RowBox[{
    "FractionalDerivative","[",
    PanelBox[
        RowBox[{
            ToBoxes @ Plot[
                f[x],
                {x,0,1},
                Axes->False,Frame->True,FrameTicks->None,
                AspectRatio->1,ImageSize->20
            ],
            "\" Order:\"",
            MakeBoxes[a,TraditionalForm]
        }],
        Background->GrayLevel[.95]
    ],
    "]"
}]
```

Now, the `RLFunction` format hides the gory details:

```
RLDerivative[1.9][Sin]
```

> [image]

Comment: A couple comments: 1. I don't think negative values for α work properly. 2. Functions with an integrable singularity at the origin won't work with this method. I could fix both issues with a bit of time.

Comment: What a nice answer!